# Nginx: Serve static files out of a given directory - one level too deep

Tags: webserver, nginx, rewrite

I'm pretty new to nginx configs. I'm having some difficulty with a pretty basic problem. I'd like to host some static files at /doc (index.html, some images, etc). The files are located in a directory called /sites/mysite/proj/doc/.

The problem is, that with the nginx config below, nginx tries to look for a directory called "/sites/mysite/proj/doc/doc". Perhaps this can be fixed by setting the root to /sites/mysite/proj/, but I don't want to potentially expose other (non-static) assets in the proj/ directory. And for various reasons, I can't really move the doc/ directory from where it is.

I think there is a way to use a Rewrite rule to solve this situation, but I don't really understand all the parts, so having some difficulty formulating the rule.

```
rewrite ^/doc/(.*)$ /$1 permanent;
```

I've also included a working example of hosting files out of a /sites/mysite/htdocs/static/ directory.

```
> vim locations.conf

location /static {
    root   /sites/mysite/htdocs/;
    access_log   off;
    autoindex  on;
}

location /doc {
    root   /sites/mysite/proj/doc/;
    access_log   on;
    autoindex  on;
}


2011/11/19 23:49:00 [error] 2314#0: *42 open() "/sites/mysite/proj/doc/doc" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 100.100.100.100, server: , request: "GET /doc HTTP/1.1", host: "myhost.com"
```

Does anyone have any ideas how I might go about serving this static content?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You could use alias, just like this:

```
location /doc {
    alias   /sites/mysite/proj/doc/;
}
```

http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#alias

Comment: It's better to use `root` instead according to the doc you referred to (see "When location matches the last part of the directive’s value")

Comment: updated doc link http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias